# Fine-grained Access Control - AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am making an employee management web-app that needs to limit what the user can see based on the user's department and position, and the department and position of the employees.

For example, below is the organizational hierarchy:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VP Unit 1 | VP Unit 2 |  |
| Director Unit 1 | Director Unit 2 | Director HR |
| Department 1 Manager | Department 2 Manager | HR Manager |
| Department 1 Supervisor | Department 2 Supervisor | HR Associate |
| Department 1 Worker | Department 2 Worker |  |

Workers and supervisors do not have access to the system. HR personnel may see all employee records for all departments/business units. Department Managers can see and create records for supervisors and workers for their own departments. Directors can see and create records for managers, supervisors, and workers for their own departments.

I am writing the app with Nextjs and AWS Amplify, which provides authentication through AWS Cognito. I want to be able to create employees/users in the app and then assign a department, and a position - which may be groups, or just custom attributes. The department seems easy enough to use @auth in the graphql schema, but for the position, I cannot think of a way to use groups to see only the next level down. If an employee is promoted, the access level to read or create records on the employee's file should change as well. Also, once the app is in production, there will not be anyone maintaining it from AdminUI so all of the functionality must be available from the app's front-end.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to find a way in your application to add a ownerField array or a a groupFieldArray to your items, and finegrain which cognito groups or which users can access each item in the db's on the db item itself.

```
type Employee 
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, read, update, delete]},
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "usersThatCanRead", operations: [read] },
    { allow: groups, groupsField: "groupsThatCanRead", operations: [read] }
  ]) {
    id: ID!
    owner: String # the full owner of the db item
    usersThatCanRead: [String] #add cognitousersub to the item in this array
    groupsThatCanRead: [String] #add cognito usergroups to the item in this array
    name: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    etc: String
  }
```